# convergence in distributon of lower bound uniform distribution - maximum likelihood

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, uniform-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Let $x_1, \cdot, x_n$ be a random sample from $U(\beta_1,\beta_2)$. 
It can be shown that $\hat{\beta_1}=min(x_1,\cdot,x_n)$ and $\hat{\beta_2}=max(x_1,\cdot,x_n)$.

Now I want to show the following statement (which was given by my professor):

$n(\hat{\beta_1}-\beta_1) \xrightarrow{d} \frac{1}{\beta_2-\beta_1}e^{\frac{x_i}{\beta_2-\beta_1}}$

I am totally stuck on this one. I only notice that the distribution of $\hat{\beta_1}=min(x_1,\cdot,x_n)$ is equal to $1-(1-F(x))^{n}$. I was also thinking about using that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1-\frac{e}{n})^n = e^{-x}$. I don't know whether I am on the right track..

Also another question: why do we have a convergence rate of $n$ rather than $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Something is incorrect here. The random variable $\frac{1}{\beta_2 - \beta_1} e^{\frac{X_1}{\beta_2-\beta_1}}$ is at most $\frac{1}{\beta_2 - \beta_1} e^{\frac{\beta_2}{\beta_2-\beta_1}}$, while there is no such upper bound on $n (\hat{\beta}_1 -\beta_1)$.  So $n(\hat{\beta}_1-\beta_1)$ cannot converge in distribution to the random variable $\frac{1}{\beta_2 - \beta_1} e^{\frac{X_1}{\beta_2-\beta_1}}$.  You likely mean something else, alluded to in the answer below.

Comment: @Michael It seems the OP's professor is writing the density of the limiting distribution (which in my opinion is really bad notation, but if the student and professor agree on the notation I guess that's ok...)

Comment: @angryavian Perhaps.  In that case there should at least be a minus sign in the exponent (and an attempt to distinguish the random variable from the PDF variable...I like the convention of using caps for random variables).

Comment: @Michael Ah apologies, I didn't notice the missing minus sign. But yes I agree with your comment about ambiguity in notation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are on the right track.
$$P(n(\hat{\beta}_1 - \beta_1) > x) = [P(X_1 > \beta_1 + x/n)]^n = \left(\frac{\beta_2 - (\beta_1 + x/n)}{\beta_2 - \beta_1}\right)^n
= \left(1 - \frac{x/(\beta_2 - \beta_1)}{n}\right)^n \to e^{-x/(\beta_2 - \beta_1)}.$$
From here you can obtain the CDF or PDF of $n(\hat{\beta}_1 - \beta_1)$ to identify the limiting distribution.

The "$n$" here shows that the convergence here is much faster than in other settings where you would typically see "$\sqrt{n}$."

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort!